# Nicer way of method chaining in Python?

Tags: python

So I have a really long chain of methods, something similar to:

```
return self.append_command("fbghasjfa").append_command(input_file_part).append_command(output_video_codec_part).append_command(output_resolution_part).append_command(output_video_bitrate_part).append_command(strict_part).append_command(output_audio_codec_part).append_command(output_number_of_audio_channels_part).append_command(output_audio_bitrate_part).append_command(output_file_part).__finalized
```

It looks quite ugly. Is there some way to put each method on a separate line? Like:

```
return self.append_command("ffasfgas")
.append_command("fvasgvsd")
.append_command("hsdhsdhsd")
#etc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either escape the newlines or parenthesize the expression.

```
foo \
.bar \
.baz

(foo
.bar
.baz)
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use backslash line continuation:

```
return self.append_command("ffasfgas") \
    .append_command("fvasgvsd") \
    .append_command("hsdhsdhsd")
```

or parentheses:

```
return (self.append_command("ffasfgas")
        .append_command("fvasgvsd")
        .append_command("hsdhsdhsd"))
```

But the most Pythonic way to do this would be to abstract the problem into a single function call:

```
return self.append_commands("ffasfgas",
                            "fvasgvsd",
                            "hsdhsdhsd")
```

Using `reduce` is another option, but not particularly elegant:

```
return reduce(MyClass.append_command, ["ffasfgas",
                                       "fvasgvsd",
                                       "hsdhsdhsd"], self)
```

or even

```
return reduce(operator.methodcaller('append_command'),
              ["ffasfgas",
               "fvasgvsd",
               "hsdhsdhsd"], self)
```

Comment: You forgot to mention using `reduce()`.

Comment: +1 for parentheses and recommendation of append_commands - Another choice could be check if append_command is a sequence but not derived from basestring and loop... But, I like this answer.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams added, but reluctantly.

Comment: Admire the 'reluctance'... ;) But yeah, if that was introduced as add_commands then fine, the user doesn't have to know it uses reduce...

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
return self.append_command("ffasfgas") \
           .append_command("fvasgvsd") \
           .append_command("hsdhsdhsd") 
# etc
```